# Why is "operator bool()" invoked when I cast to "long"?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, casting, operators

I have the following class:

```
class MyClass {
public:
   MyClass( char* what ) : controlled( what ) {}
   ~MyClass() { delete[] controlled; }
   operator char*() const { return controlled; }
   operator void*() const { return controlled; }
   operator bool() const { return controlled != 0; }

private:
   char* controlled;
};
```

This is compiled with Microsoft SDK that has the following typedefs:

```
typedef long LONG_PTR;
typedef LONG_PTR LPARAM;
```

The calling code does the following:

```
MyClass instance( new char[1000] );
LPARAM castResult = (LPARAM)instance;
// Then we send message intending to pass the address of the buffer inside MyClass
::SendMessage( window, message, wParam, castResult );
```

Suddenly `castResult` is `1` - `MyClass::operator bool()` is invoked, it returns `true` which is converted to `1`. So instead of passing the address I pass `1` into `SendMessage()` which leads to undefined behaviour.

But why is `operator bool()` invoked in the first place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's one of the known pitfalls of using operator bool, that is a aftershock of C inheritance. You'd definitively benefit from reading about the [Safe Bool Idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html).

In general, you didn't provide any other matchable casting operator, and bool (unfortunately) is treated as a good source for arithmetic casting.

Answer (score 5):

`operator bool` is the best match, because `char*` and `void*` can't be converted to `long` without an explicit cast, unlike `bool`:

```
long L1 = (void*)instance; // error
long L2 = (char*)instance; // error
long L3 = (bool)instance; // ok
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot implicitly cast a `T*` to long. But you can cast a bool to long.

So the `operator bool` is used.

You have to define a `operator LPARAM`.

Comment: Or rather remove all of the conversion operators. Only `operator void*` is considered relatively benign if you wish to allow evaluating the object in boolean context (used in standard C++ library, but makes for example `std::cout << std::cin;` produce somewhat unintuitive results), even though there are even surer techniques.