# what does the operator string() { some code } do?

Tags: c++

I have the following code in a class:

```
operator string() {
        return format("CN(%d)", _fd);
}
```

And wanted to know what this operator does.

I am familiar with the usual string operators:

```
bool operator==(const string& c1, const string& c2);
bool operator!=(const string& c1, const string& c2);
bool operator<(const string& c1, const string& c2);
bool operator>(const string& c1, const string& c2);
bool operator<=(const string& c1, const string& c2);
bool operator>=(const string& c1, const string& c2);
string operator+(const string& s1, const string& s2 );
string operator+(const Char* s, const string& s2 );
string operator+( Char c, const string& s2 );
string operator+( const string& s1, const Char* s );
string operator+( const string& s1, Char c );
string& operator+=(const string& append);
string& operator+=(const Char* append);
string& operator+=(const Char  append);
ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, const string& s );
istream& operator>>( istream& is, string& s );
string& operator=( const string& s );
string& operator=( const Char* s );
string& operator=( Char ch );
Char& operator[]( size_type index );
const Char& operator[]( size_type index ) const;
```

... but not this one?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
operator Type() { ... }
```

is the (implicit) *conversion operator*. For example, if class `Animal` implements `operator string()`, then the code

```
Animal a;
...
do_something_with ( (string)a );
```

will become something like

```
do_something_with ( (Animal::operator string)(&a) );
```

See http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr385.htm for some more examples.

Comment: +1 for referring to it by its proper name, conversion operator.

Comment: A good example is the oft used `operator bool() { ... }` which allows an object of the type to be used in `if (object) { ... } else { ... }` which for example in container types could be implemented as meaning true to be non-empty.

Comment: @wich: `operator bool` can give you unexpected behavior http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145931/why-is-operator-bool-invoked-when-i-cast-to-long.

Comment: As a side note, such implicit conversions are generally considered a bad idea

Comment: +1 I think that `do_something_with( a.operator string() )` can be a better way of expressing how the compiler interprets the code. Also if the example defined a function taking a string (const &) as argument it would also show why it is _implicit_, as you point out in the answer.

Comment: @wich In C++11 we use `explicit operator bool()`.

Answer (score 9):

It's overloading the conversion operator. A class which has the function

```
operator string();
```

defined can be converted to a string.

Comment: it's got nothing to do with casting, it's type conversion, that that may happen due to a cast is another matter.

Answer (score 2):

If just returns a string represantation of your current object, e.g. for printing it on the console.

Comment: More specifically, it's a conversion operator for converting to type `string`. You can create conversion operators targeting other types too.

Answer (score 2):

It is an automatic type conversion operator. This class you are talking about can be implicitly converted to a string. This [link](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/tic/tic0131.shtml) might help you with a few more examples.

Answer (score -2):

That would appear to be a cast-to-string operator for a decimal number type.