# Cant understand this statement - Return Type after operator

Tags: c++, c++98

I came across the following code and the method of the class confused me

```
class X
{
    ......
    operator string () const {return "X"}
    ......
}
```

Normally the return type is in front of the method. I would appreciate it if someone could explain what this statement does and details regarding this statement

Comment: implicit conversion operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an `operator()` that returns a `string` written in a strange way (as you probably thought), it is an implicit conversion operator that can be used to covert the `X` type to a `string` type:

```
X a;
string B = static_cast<string>(a);
```

Also, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239380/what-does-the-operator-string-some-code-do).

Answer (score 3):

A **conversion operator** is a special kind of member function that converts a value of a class type to a value of some other type. It typically looks like this:

```
operator type() const;
```

where `type` represents a type. In your example, it's used to implicitly convert a value of class `X` to a `string`.